# Is it possibile that a server timeouts when asked too many requests?

Tags: android, http, connection, timeout, server

I'm developing an Android application, which among its workflow has to process a series of requests to a remote server (that is actually just a website - it responds with HTML). I'm using Volley and OkHttp.

Let's put in this way: I have something like this:

```
private void refresh() {    
    for (Call call : listOfCalls) {
        addToQueue(call); // because of Volley mechanism, this also executes the request
    }
}

@Override
public void callback() {
    // I expect this method to be called listOfCalls.size() times
}
```

The number of calls is around 10, and based on my tests they are processed in about 10-15 ms. This means that the server has to handle to something like 1 call per 1/2 milliseconds, from the very same client.

Everything is fine when I'm in debug mode, and I force the calls to be sent separately, each one every 1-2 seconds. But whenever I try to burst the series of calls all at once, suddenly the backend starts doing, but only on **some calls**, and without any apparent pattern, two very weird things:

- it simply timeouts (and I set a timeout of around 10 seconds, so it's not a normal behaviour)
- it provides an empty content: `Content-Length: 0` (and I specifically set the internal cache to null, so it's not something related to that).

Please, note also that even if I try to execute each call only **after** the previous one has finished (so, in the case that it's `callback()` which calls the next request in the queue, and `refresh()` just makes the first), I still stumble in the same problem. The only thing that changes is the fact that it stops to provide empty body - it just timeouts.

So my question is: Is it possibile that this server is implementing some sort of "control", so that whenever the very same client starts doing too many requests in a very short amout of time, it starts to respond in an uncommon way (i.e. timeouts and provides `Content-Length: 0`)?
And thus, that the only workaround is actually stopping the client with an arbitrary "time-off" - "pause" - between each call?

Comment: Yes, some server are having such mechanism to prevent Denial of Service attacks (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial_of_Service).